# Simple Validate for Months with Jquery

Tags: jquery

What Im trying to do is validate a text field with just jquery. So What I want it to do is basically look into an array with the month names, and lets say the person spells the month wrong it doesnt submit.

I'm not sure how to begin this.

Comment: Wouldn't a drop down be a better solution to avoid typing mistakes?

Comment: thats exactly what I did. Client doesn't like it. So... you know what that means.

Comment: another good solution would be some kind of DatePicker
(i.e. to avoid dates like 02/30 etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think j089691 comments is right on mark.  There's probably better ways to do this.

If, for some reason, you want to do this... you can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/uTRXb/

Comment: Instead of using a huge Array you could use a regex

Comment: well... I guess one could use a regex.  The question does specify an "array with month names".  Could you post the regex expression?

Comment: \January|February|...|December\